# How do I define a TypeAdapter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am currently using the Hive database to store data. I run the below code:

```dart
main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(exerciseAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox('exerciseBox');
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
}
```

But it says *exerciseAdapter() is not defined*. How do I register this type adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your imports, but it seems you haven't defined the `exerciseAdapter()` method or imported it from another file. To register a type adapter in Hive, you need to create a custom adapter for your class (e.g., Exercise) and then register it using `Hive.registerAdapter()`.

First, you need to create the custom adapter for your Exercise class. Assuming you have a class called Exercise, follow these steps:

Add hive_generator and build_runner dependencies to your pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  hive: ^2.2.3
  ...

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  ...
```

Create a file for your Exercise class (e.g., `exercise.dart`) and import the required packages:

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'exercise.g.dart';
```

Define your Exercise class and annotate it with @HiveType:

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Exercise extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  int duration;

  Exercise({required this.name, required this.duration});
}
```

Run the build command to generate the adapter file `exercise.g.dart`:

```dart
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Finally, import the generated adapter file and register it in your main() function:

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'exercise.dart';

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(ExerciseAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Exercise>('exerciseBox');

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Where do I access the generated adapter file to import it?

Comment: @nsa41620 The generated adapter file will be in the same directory as your Exercise class file It has the same name as your class file, but with a .g.dart extension. For example, if your Exercise class is defined in a file called exercise.dart, the generated adapter file will be named exercise.g.dart.